# Close button doesn't work in Angular UI Modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

In this [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/fqJkSAGooBfOLKeM91T2?p=preview) I have an Angular UI Modal and a button to close it. The button doesn't work because the Modal instance doesn't have a `close` method.

If you remove the `rendered` statement, the button works. Why doesn't it work WITH `rendered`?

This DOESN'T work:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,$uibModal) {

        $scope.openModal = function() {
          $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
              templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
              scope: $scope
            }).rendered.then(function() {
                 alert("modal rendered")
            }); 
        };

        $scope.close = function () {
            $scope.modalInstance.close();
        };

})
```

This DOES work (see [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/CkABmRuefWxXC3K8Axpa?p=preview)):

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,$uibModal) {

        $scope.openModal = function() {
          $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
              templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
              scope: $scope
            }); 
        };

        $scope.close = function () {
            $scope.modalInstance.close();
        };

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you are assigning the `rendered` promise to `$scopemodalInstance`, not the instance. It works if you do something like ([Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/msM8WxWcBmvxXIFefhG0?p=preview)):

```
$scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    scope: $scope
});
$scope.modalInstance.rendered.then(function() {
    alert("modal rendered")
});
```